# How to submit a form with JavaScript using python Requests?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, forms

I have a page as follows.
[www.pict.ethdigitalcampus.com](http://www.pict.ethdigitalcampus.com)

I wish to submit the form data on this page using python Requests.
But unfortunately on this website, when the Submit button is clicked it calls a validate function.

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="return validate();" style="font-family: Verdana">
```

Now this validate function actually encrypts the password using some algorithm and then submits it to the server.
This is how the validate function works:

```
function validate()
{
    if(isBlank(document.loginForm.loginid.value) || isNull(document.loginForm.loginid.value))
    {
        alert('Please Enter Login Id.');
        document.loginForm.loginid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(isBlank(document.loginForm.password.value) || isNull(document.loginForm.password.value))
    {
        alert('Please Enter Password.');
        document.loginForm.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var hashObj = new jsSHA("mySuperPassword", "ASCII");
    var password = hashObj.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX");

    var textval =document.loginForm.password.value; //The actual password entered by the user
    var encryptedString = $.jCryption.encrypt(textval, password); //The password is encrypted and stored

    document.loginForm.password.value = encryptedString; //The password field of the form is updated with "encrypedString" 
    document.loginForm.hiddenfield.value=password;
    document.loginForm.service_id.value=get_cookie(document.loginForm.loginid.value.toUpperCase());
    document.loginForm.action="http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com:80/DCWeb/authenticate.do";

    return true;
}
```

Now since I cannot directly submit form data to the action page, I have no choice but to click that button and execute this JavaScript function.

I have tried using urllib and still no luck. What do I do?

Comment: If you want to use `requests` or `urllib` or any other python HTTP libraries you can only implement the use encryption mechanism in python and then send the generated data directly to the specified endpoint.

Comment: Selenium ?  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: The whole purpose of trying to do what I am doing is to do a desired task with a script. Selenium has further requirements like a browser which I don't intend to complete. Although I know using some methods the popping of browser can be silenced but I have no intention of going that way.